# How do you call The app.js function from another Component

Tags: react-native

I have this in my App.js:

```
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Login"
    component={() => <Login call={callFromLogin}/>}
    options={{headerShown: false,}}
  />
```

And this:

```
const callFromLogin = () => {
  console.log("App");
}
```

So when i reach login component i call the function "call":

```
const Login = ({navigation, call}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        call()
    }, []);

}
```

But I get an error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 6):
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

How can I call a function in App.js from another component?